# customize countdown script for restart every 8 hours

Tags: javascript, countdown

the below script and short code for countdown plugin , i want to change short code to achieve things i want please customize my short code cause i need these below points

1- i want to work countdown with out start date and end date , i mean i want countdown working every 8 hours and when finish start again with new 8 hours

2- i need to know exactly what the time zone here dose it mean ?

3- i want when countdown finish after 8 hours , refresh page and start again countdown with new 8 hours

- now this is short code i want to customize

> [circularcountdown task="update" startDate="2015/10/29 00:00:002015/10/29 00:00:00" endDate="2015/11/30 00:00:002015/10/30 00:00:00" timeZone="8" past="false" margin="10" onFinish="function() {}" showDay="true" showHour="true" showMinute="true" showSecond="true" dayDiameter="160" hourDiameter="160" minuteDiameter="160" secondDiameter="160" dayBgWidth="23" hourBgWidth="23" minuteBgWidth="23" secondBgWidth="23" dayCircleWidth="23" hourCircleWidth="23" minuteCircleWidth="23" secondCircleWidth="23" dayBgColor="#cccccc" hourBgColor="#cccccc" minuteBgColor="#cccccc" secondBgColor="#cccccc" dayCircleColor="#e8065c" hourCircleColor="#e8065c" minuteCircleColor="#e8065c" secondCircleColor="#e8065c" dayCounterFontSize="32" hourCounterFontSize="32" minuteCounterFontSize="32" secondCounterFontSize="32" dayTextFontSize="11" hourTextFontSize="11" minuteTextFontSize="11" secondTextFontSize="11" dayCounterFontColor="#333333" hourCounterFontColor="#333333" minuteCounterFontColor="#333333" secondCounterFontColor="#333333" dayTextFontColor="#666666" hourTextFontColor="#666666" minuteTextFontColor="#666666" secondTextFontColor="#666666" dayText="DAYS" hourText="HOURS" minuteText="MINUTES" secondText="SECONDS" dayTextMarginTop="0" hourTextMarginTop="0" minuteTextMarginTop="0" secondTextMarginTop="0"]

- this is the script from inspect elements from google chrome in website

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#circularcountdown_JcVyzyji").circularCountdown({
   startDate:"2015/10/29 00:00:002015/10/29 00:00:00",
   endDate:"2015/11/30 00:00:002015/10/30 00:00:00",
   timeZone:8,
   past:false,
   
   //Show-hide day, hour, minute, second
   showDay:true,
   showHour:true,
   showMinute:true,
   showSecond:true,
   
   //Margin between circles
   margin:10,
   
   //Diameters
   dayDiameter:160,
   hourDiameter:160,
   minuteDiameter:160,
   secondDiameter:160,
   
   //Circle BG width
   dayBgWidth:23,
   hourBgWidth:23,
   minuteBgWidth:23,
   secondBgWidth:23,
   
   //Circle width
   dayCircleWidth:23,
   hourCircleWidth:23,
   minuteCircleWidth:23,
   secondCircleWidth:23,
   
   //Circle BG color
   dayBgColor:"#cccccc",
   hourBgColor:"#cccccc",
   minuteBgColor:"#cccccc",
   secondBgColor:"#cccccc",
   
   //Circle color
   dayCircleColor:"#e8065c",
   hourCircleColor:"#e8065c",
   minuteCircleColor:"#e8065c",
   secondCircleColor:"#e8065c",
   
   //Counter font size
   dayCounterFontSize:32,
   hourCounterFontSize:32,
   minuteCounterFontSize:32,
   secondCounterFontSize:32,
   
   //Text font size
   dayTextFontSize:11,
   hourTextFontSize:11,
   minuteTextFontSize:11,
   secondTextFontSize:11,
   
   //Counter font color
   dayCounterFontColor:"#333333",
   hourCounterFontColor:"#333333",
   minuteCounterFontColor:"#333333",
   secondCounterFontColor:"#333333",
   
   //Text font color
   dayTextFontColor:"#666666",
   hourTextFontColor:"#666666",
   minuteTextFontColor:"#666666",
   secondTextFontColor:"#666666",
   
   //Texts
   dayText:"DAYS",
   hourText:"HOURS",
   minuteText:"MINUTES",
   secondText:"SECONDS",
   
   //Texts top margin
   dayTextMarginTop:0,
   hourTextMarginTop:0,
   minuteTextMarginTop:0,
   secondTextMarginTop:0,
   
   //Timer on finish function
   onFinish:function() {}  });
 });
</script>
```

sorry for little english

Comment: where`s professional ??? i need help

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function reset(){
        location.reload(); // reload page
    }
    setTimeout(reset, 28800000); // reset page in 8 hours, milliseconds
 </script>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for reply but i want to customize short code , how cai do this with your code ,

Comment: by the way i tried to put this code in js but there is error

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.